# How to create Resource Manager for Game

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to make an "resource manager" for my 2D game with c++.
The initial idea is anything like this:

```
class resource_manager
{
private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<texture> > all_textures;

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<texture> texture_load(std::string path)
    {
        // if path no exist in map all_textures:
        // load texture, store in map, return the pointer.          
        // else: only return the pointer.
    }       
protected
    resource_manager() {}
    ~resource_manager() {}  
};


class texture
{
private:
    unsigned  id; // opengl texture id
    unsigned  width;
    unsigned  height;       

public:
    texture(unsigned _id, unsigned _width, unsigned _height) 
        : id(_id), width(_width), height(_height)   {}
    ~texture() {}

    // getters and setters          
};
```

But, i have a problem. When the shared_ptr counter come to < 0, the pointer of texture will be destroyed, ok, but my texture still continues in VGA memory. So, when the pointer destruct herself, i need call `glDeleteTextures()` to unload the texture in memory.

C++ is not my speciality, for that, is hard to me do it.
Sorry for my poor english. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Call `glDeleteTextures()` in the destructor of texture...

Comment: I cant do it, each texture can used for one or more objects.

Comment: The destructor will be called only when the count goes to 0... That's the whole point of shared_ptr. So when none of your objects reference the texture anymore the destructor for it is called (which calls `glDeleteTextures()`) and all will be fine.

Comment: lol, is so obvious, thanks.